# How can i calculate Confidence interval of the mean for over dispersed count data?

Tags: confidence-interval

I have count data that is highly over-dispersed ( Variance is greater than 10 times mean) . I would like to calculate 95% and 98% confidence intervals for the mean.  How can i calculate the standard error? How many standard errors for each CI?

I'm assuming poisson is inappropriate because of over-dispersion.

Comment: Would you be using the Poisson assumption anyways for constructing a confidence interval?  Generally you'd use a normal approximation for the sample mean, where any relationship between the underlying mean and variance wouldn't really be important.

Comment: I could do, but i'm also using a negative binomial regression analysing the same data and i suspect it would raise eyebrows if i wasn't consistent. is there a standard error formula for a mean of a negative binomial distribution? Or should i just be pragmatic and use Poisson? while i'm asking i've been using the following to calculate poison SEs : sqrt((mean*(1-mean)/sample size) is that correct? I got the forumula from : http://www.kurtosis.co.uk/technique/funnel_plot.htm

Comment: No, that's the standard error for a binomial proportion.  Your original post doesn't mention regression, so what exactly is the problem you're working on?  It sounded as though you just had samples from a single distribution and wanted to estimate a mean.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have a NBR producing expected values for a count response variable, based on a count predictor. the dependent variable is a number of events per x number of trials, so binomial does sound the right distribution. I'm trying to create a confidence interval for the expected number of events accounting for varying population sizes between observations ( essentially, like a funnel plot - each observation is a geographical area with different population sizes). based on this discussion, i think using the standard error for a binomial proportion makes sense. Any thoughts?